# Prometheus IPv6 fails with "connect: invalid argument"

Tags: ipv6, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I am currently trying to setup an internal Prometheus monitoring system that must use IPv6. My static config does not work though:

```
- targets: ['[fe80::3086:7bff:fed8:f402]:9100']
```

This fails with the error

Get http://[fe80::3086:7bff:fed8:f402]:9100/metrics: dial tcp [fe80::3086:7bff:fed8:f402]:9100: connect: invalid argument

---

I tried using CURL to see if I can even connect to the remote server where node-exporter is running.

This didn't work: `curl -g -6 'http://[fe80::3086:7bff:fed8:f402]:9100/metrics'`

But this did work: `curl -g -6 'http://[fe80::3086:7bff:fed8:f402%ens17]:9100/metrics'`

This showed me that I am in fact able to connect to the server but have to add the network interface that connects top the IPv6 network into the URL. I honestly have no idea why.

But now, the same URL does not work for prometheus, which still has an error:

```
- targets: ['[fe80::3086:7bff:fed8:f402%ens17]:9100']

Get http://[fe80::3086:7bff:fed8:f402%25ens17]:9100/metrics: dial tcp [fe80::3086:7bff:fed8:f402%ens17]:9100: connect: invalid argument
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using IPv6 Link-Local addressing, you must add the Zone ID (`%ens17` in your case) to explain which interface is meant. Every interface will have the same Link-Local network, so you must distinguish which interface, and the Zone ID does that for you.

This is detailed in several RFCs. You should at least be familiar with [RFC 2732, Format for Literal IPv6 Addresses in URL's](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt), [RFC 4007, IPv6 Scoped Address Architecture](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4007), and [RFC 6874, Representing IPv6 Zone Identifiers in Address Literals and Uniform Resource Identifiers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6874).

---

Unfortunately, not everything seems to have caught up with this, and the `%` is often used as the escape character. What you should really do is assign ULA addressing (`fc00::/7`) to your hosts. Set the `L` bit to one (`fd00::/8`), then select a random 40-bit Global ID (`fdxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64`), and assign addresses to your hosts from the prefix you derived. If you have multiple networks, you can use the same method to get a prefix for each network, and you can route the ULA addressing (unlike Link-Local addressing) within your own site.

[RFC 4193, Unique Local IPv6 Unicast Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193) explains the IPv6 ULA addressing.

Comment: Uh, thanks. I might take a while to test this. This is way more complicated that I thought :/

Comment: It is really not all that complicated, just different thinking than with IPv4. With IPv4, you really would not try to use Link-Local addressing, you would probably use Private addressing. Private addressing has a problem in that it is used on multiple networks, so it makes connecting between or merging companies very complex. IPv6 ULA solves that by giving you a very high probability that your own addressing is unique by using a 40-bit random Global ID.